# Cramming data into a single statement

Tags: c

Take the following word-count program I have, where a word is (naively) taken as `alnum`s between `whitespace`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    // grab a segment of text until EOF
    int current_char;
    int num_words=0, num_chars=0, num_lines=0; // ignore whitespace
    bool in_word;

    printf("Enter your text here:\n");

    while ((current_char=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (current_char == '\n')
            in_word ? num_words++, num_lines ++, in_word-- : num_lines++;
        else if (isalnum(current_char))
            num_chars ++, in_word=true;
        else if (isspace(current_char))
            in_word ? num_words++, in_word-- : ' ';
    }
    if (in_word) num_words ++;

    printf("\nChar Count: %d | Line count: %d | Word count: %d\n", num_chars, num_lines, num_words);

}
```

Ignoring the naivety of the word-detection, is this considered bad practice to cram things into a single statement so braces can be skipped? For example, I suppose the 'long-form' version of the first `if` would be:

```
if (current_char == '\n')
{
    num_lines ++;
    if (in_word)
        num_words ++;
    in_word = false;
}
```

This seems more readable and easy for me to understand, but often I'll see long one-liners in C and so I was wondering why one choice may be used over the other.

For example, here's a line from [`postgres`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/881933f194221abcce07fb134ebe8685e5bb58dd/src/backend/parser/parse_agg.c#L1069)  which seems to be like a too-long-one-liner that I have a difficult time understanding:

```
if (!gsets)
    ereport(ERROR,
        (errcode(ERRCODE_STATEMENT_TOO_COMPLEX),
        errmsg("too many grouping sets present (maximum 4096)"),
        parser_errposition(pstate,
            qry->groupClause
            ? exprLocation((Node *) qry->groupClause)
            : exprLocation((Node *) qry->groupingSets))));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227818/discussion-on-question-by-samuelbrody1249-cramming-data-into-a-single-statement).

Comment: The main rule of thumb to apply here is which is more readable and easier to make changes to? It is often instructive to write the same code multiple ways and then evaluate the pros and cons of each, including readability.